# Как сделать зависимость координат в Swift?

Tags: swift, разработка-игр

Персонаж может двигать ящик, если он стоит на том месте, куда персонаж хочет попасть. Главное что ни один объект не может покинуть пределы комнаты. Подвигайте ящик :)

Понимаю, для знатоков это простой вопрос. Но я swift учу всего третью неделю. Смотрю уроки, но как сделать зависимость Box от Pers понять в корне не могу.

Поясните на пальцах, как это сделать.

```
struct Pers {
    var x : Int
    var y : Int

    enum Direction {
        case Left
        case Right
        case Up
        case Down
    }

    mutating func switchMove(direction: Direction, var position: Pers) -> Pers {
        switch direction {
            case .Right : if self.y < 10 && self.y >= 1 {self.y += 1}           // plusY()
            case .Up :    if self.x < 10 && self.x >= 0 {self.x += 1}           //plusX()
            case .Down :  if self.x <= 10 && self.x >= 1 {self.x -= 1}          // minusX()
            case .Left :  if self.y <= 10 && self.y >= 1 {self.y -= 1}          //minusY()
        }
        return position
    }
}

struct Box {
    var x : Int
    var y : Int
}

var pers = Pers(x: 6, y: 5)
var box = Box(x: 5, y: 5)

print("\(pers)")
print("\(box)")
```

Comment: Код в виде текста вставьте, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 2):

Из простейшего - в направлениях

```
case .Right : if self.y < 10 && self.y >= 0 {self.y += 1}           // plusY()
case .Up :    if self.x < 10 && self.x >= 0 {self.x += 1}           //plusX()
case .Down :  if self.x <= 10 && self.x >= 1 {self.x -= 1}          // minusX()
case .Left :  if self.y <= 10 && self.y >= 1 {self.y -= 1}
```

не просто изменяйте значение по координате на 1, а проверяйте, есть ли там ящик:

```
/*пример для Вашего .Right*/ 
if box.x == self.x && (self.y+1) == box.y { //проверим, на пути ли ящик
    if box.y < 10 && box.y >= 0 && { //здесь можно подискутировать насчет box.y >= 0
        self.y += 1
        box.y += 1
    } else {
        //нельзя сдвинуть
    }
} else {
    self.y += 1
} //надеюсь по коду ничего не упустил
```

Если есть, проверьте, можно ли его подвинуть. Если можно, то изменяете координату на +1 как у `Box`, так и `Pers`. Если нельзя, то ничего не делать(уведомить, что дальше не передвинуться, там ящик, а ящик у стены)